# Search a string against multiple string arrays

Tags: c++

I have a input string and need to run through it and see if it matches certain words. I have multiple string arrays but not sure whats an efficient way to check the string agianst all the arrays.

String Arrays:

```
 string checkPlayType(string printDescription)
{
    const string DeepPassRight[3] = {"deep" , "pass" , "right"};
    const string DeepPassLeft[3] = {"deep" , "pass" , "left"};
    const string DeepPassMiddle[3] = {"deep" , "pass" , "middle"};

    const string ShortPassRight[3] = {"short" , "pass" , "right"};
    const string ShortPassLeft[3] = {"short" , "pass" , "left"};
    const string ShortPassMiddle[3] = {"short" , "pass" , "middle"};

    //Must contain right but not pass
    const string RunRight = "right";
    //Must contain right but not pass
    const string RunLeft = "left";
    //Must contain middle but not pass      
    const string RunMiddle = "middle";

    const string FieldGoalAttempt[2] = {"field" , "goal" };
    const string Punt = "punt";

}

Sample Input: (13:55) (Shotgun) P.Manning pass incomplete short right to M.Harrison.

Assuming this is our only input...
Sample Output: 
Deep Pass Right: 0%
Deep Pass Left: 0%
Deep Pass Middle: 0%
Short Pass Right: 100%
Shor Pass Left:0%
...
..
..
```

Comment: Why do you have all of these separate string arrays instead of a single dictionary to loop through?

Comment: I have to identify what type of play it is and then output the percentage that play happens

Comment: Can you give example input and desired output?

Comment: Take a look  at Boyer Moore or KMP algorithms if you want to write them yourself. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm#KMP_algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm#Description_2

Comment: Updated with sample input/output

Comment: It may be more effective to use a state machine for this.  That is, scan the input for the word "pass", set the "passing" state to true, then scan it for "long" (or "short"), etc.

Comment: This would better be asked at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. 

Answer (score 3):

you may want something similar to:

```
void checkPlayType(const std::vector<std::string>& input)
{
    std::set<std::string> s;

    for (const auto& word : input) {
        s.insert(word);
    }
    const bool deep_present = s.count("deep");
    const bool pass_present = s.count("pass");
    const bool right_present = s.count("right");
    const bool left_present = s.count("left");
    // ...

    if (deep_present && pass_present && right_present) { /* increase DeepPassRight counter */}
    if (deep_present && pass_present && left_present) { /* increase DeepPassLeft counter */}
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @moswald: I agree, your edit is more comprehensible (use short circuit `&&` instead of bitwise `&`). The version with `&` is correct too and use less branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can go over your arrays and search for the words are stored in the array within the input string. Use std functions for better performance. For example:

```
const string DeepPassRight[3] = {"deep" , "pass" , "right"};
    int i = 0;
    for(;i<3;i++)
    {
        string s = " ";
        s.append(DeepPassRight[i]);
        s.append(" ");
        std::size_t found = printDescription.find(s);
        if (found ==std::string::npos)
           break;

    }
    if(i == 3)
        // printDescription contains all DeepPassRight's members!
if(i== 2)
// just two words were found
```

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expressions:

```
if found "pass" then
    if regexp "(deep|short).*(left|right|middle)"
        Hooray!
    else if regexp "(left|right|middle).*(deep|short)"
        Hooray!
    else
        Aye, Caramba!
else
    Aye, Caramba!
```